# Link Bootstrap Button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a piece of code in my flask application that I want to implement a button that takes me to an specific page.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Evaluate</button>
```

How do I link the button? I did putting an  tag wrapping it, but can I use the tag  directly? (Using the  tag is changing my styling)

*I did the code below, but it is not good for me

```
<a href="{{url_for('evaluate')}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Evaluate</button></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<a>` tag instead

```
<a href="someUrl" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Evaluate</a>
```

use the `href` attribute to navigate to the new location.

Bootstrap will take care of presenting the `<a>` tag as a button with the css classes.

Comment: Great. You can marks the answer as correct if you think it will help others with similar problems.